# SharePoint 2010 Filter Web-parts are not working

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server

I am using some OOB web-parts in SharePoint 2010 like text filter ,Excel Web-access and sql analysis filter web-part  and tried to give connection between these filter web-parts .Even I tried to give connections between Text Filter and List I found same issue .Can any one let me know is it environment issue or Do i need to any configuration to perform this operation
[image]

Comment: whats the error its displaying? cant read the error on the image!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cant see any errors?

Im taking a guess that based on your question your trying to connect two filter webparts together?

I dont think that is possible! filter connection is a many to 1 relation (many filters to one data source)

by that i mean you can connect different filters to a datasource(list/doc lib webpart or dataview / datatable webpart or source). Filters cant connect to other filters and then to a data source!

what exactly are you trying todo? that way i could advise you on the best solution.

> Filter Web Parts can be very useful in data-rich business intelligence
>   sites. They provide a user interface (usually, and can be hidden) that
>   allows the user to provide search or **filter criteria** for a query **on
>   data such as a database table or a list**. When you connect a filter Web
>   Part to one or more Web Parts on the page that have filtering
>   capability, they display filtered results of the query.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms494838(v=office.12).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms494838%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

you get the connection option available because its two webparts, otherwise it will fail as there is no data source.

Comment: Thank you very much Ali . After changing the master to v4.master it worked

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to use 'Choice Filter' webpart, after adding filter webpart i could not able to see the webpart.
But You can check the same by adding  the query string ?contents=1 at the page url. You will be able to see the list of webparts in the page where you can see your filter webparts too.
You will not get this issue if you add webparts in a webpart page.

**Reason:**  The problem occurs because the WebPartManager.DisplayMode property is not getting set when the page is edited. The web parts expect to check WebPartManager.DisplayMode.AllowPageDesign, but for these pages it is set to BrowseDisplayMode even when editing.

**Solution:** To see the filter web part you’ll need to select “Edit Web Part” for any of the existing web parts you already have on the page. You can then see the newly added filter web parts you have added to the page and also configure them.

Answer (score -1):

It seems like you need to enable Server Render for the List webpart under Miscellaneous category.

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange Community... You need to provide detailed solutions to problems also try to add relevant reference to support your answer...